# Sproutcore 2.0 Text field focus event

Tags: sproutcore-2

Does anyone know where can I find the even list of a Text Field?

I need the focus event, and can't find his name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to set focus, you can just use jQuery:

```
$('#textFieldId').focus();
```

If you wish to handle events, see [SC.EventDispatcher](https://github.com/sproutcore/sproutcore20/blob/master/packages/sproutcore-views/lib/system/event_dispatcher.js) for a list of supported events.  I think you want `focusIn` or `focusOut`.

```
 var event, events = {
  touchstart  : 'touchStart',
  touchmove   : 'touchMove',
  touchend    : 'touchEnd',
  touchcancel : 'touchCancel',
  keydown     : 'keyDown',
  keyup       : 'keyUp',
  keypress    : 'keyPress',
  mousedown   : 'mouseDown',
  mouseup     : 'mouseUp',
  click       : 'click',
  dblclick    : 'doubleClick',
  mousemove   : 'mouseMove',
  focusin     : 'focusIn',
  focusout    : 'focusOut',
  mouseenter  : 'mouseEnter',
  mouseleave  : 'mouseLeave',
  submit      : 'submit',
  change      : 'change',
  dragstart   : 'dragStart',
  drag        : 'drag',
  dragenter   : 'dragEnter',
  dragleave   : 'dragLeave',
  dragover    : 'dragOver',
  drop        : 'drop',
  dragend     : 'dragEnd'
};
```

For example:

```
App.TextBoxView = SC.TextField.extend({
    attributeBindings: ['type', 'placeholder', 'value', 'name', 'tabindex', 'disabled', 'readonly'],

    name: '',

    tabindex: '1',

    disabled: NO,

    readonly: NO,

    focusIn: function(event) {
       // your code
       return false;
    },

    focusOut: function(event) {
       this._elementValueDidChange();
       return false;
    }
});
```